# How do I convert a dataframe to parquet file and upload on Azure Blob storage in R? Any working examples?

Tags: r, azure-storage, parquet, sparkr

This seems to work for csv but I need to upload a Parquet file

```
library(AzureStor)


bl_endp_key <- storage_endpoint("url", key="key")
cont <- storage_container(bl_endp_key, "containername")
csv <- serialize(dataframe, connection = NULL, ascii = TRUE)
con <- rawConnection(csv)
upload_blob(cont, src=con, dest="output.csv")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `arrow` package to write R data frames to Parquet files. See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/

Comment: Converting to parquet is not a problem, the issue is uploading it on the blob storage. I tried write_parquet(dataframe,"/mnt/temp/test.parquet")
r_con <- rawConnection("/mnt/temp/test.parquet")
upload_blob(cont, src=r_con, dest="test.parquet")....got an error invalid 'raw' argument